# typescript multi-parameter type association constraint issue

Tags: typescript

I meet a typescript multi-parameter type constraint issue.

Firstly there is a running ok example:

```js
interface ABC {
  abc: 1;
}

interface XYZ {
  xyz: 2;
}

interface HahaParams {
  type: 'haha';
  value: ABC;
  gen: number;
}

interface YoyoParams {
  type: 'yoyo';
  value: XYZ;
  gen: string;
}

type Params = HahaParams | YoyoParams;

function test<
  T extends Params['type'],
  V extends Extract<Params, {type: T}>['value'],
  G extends Extract<Params, {type: T}>['gen'],
>(
  type: T,
  value: V,
  gen: G,
){
  console.log(type, value, gen);
}

test('haha', {abc: 1}, 1); // run ok

test('haha', {xyz: 2}, 1); // type error, i get an error as expected as below
// TS2345: Argument of type '{ xyz: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ABC'. 
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'xyz' does not exist in type 'ABC'.
```

The first example is running ok, the type error is expected.

But when i change the type of parameter 'gen' to function, then the error will arise, see the example:

```js
interface ABC {
  abc: 1;
}

interface XYZ {
  xyz: 2;
}

interface HahaParams {
  type: 'haha';
  value: ABC;
  gen: (abc: ABC) => void;
}

interface YoyoParams {
  type: 'yoyo';
  value: XYZ;
  gen: (xyz: XYZ) => void;
}

type Params = HahaParams | YoyoParams;

function test<
  T extends Params['type'],
  V extends Extract<Params, {type: T}>['value'],
  G extends Extract<Params, {type: T}>['gen'],
>(
  type: T,
  value: V,
  gen: G,
){
  console.log(type, value, gen(value)); // type error, is get an unexpected:
// TS2345: Argument of type 'ABC | XYZ' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ABC & XYZ'.
// Type 'ABC' is not assignable to type 'ABC & XYZ'.
// Property 'xyz' is missing in type 'ABC' but required in type 'XYZ'.
}

test('haha', {abc: 1}, (n) => n);
```

So as you see, according to the first example, i think the parameter 'gen' should be narrowed to type "HahaParams['gen']" or "YoyoParams['gen']":

```js
(abc: ABC) => ABC
```

or

```js
(xyz: XYZ) => XYZ
```

But the typescript compiler shows it should be

```js
(arg0: ABC & XYZ) => ABC | XYZ
```

I don't know what happens in the second example, does that i change the 'gen' parameter's type to function affects the type judgment of the compiler.

Is my thought wrong? How can i fix it?

Comment: You can call `test()` with `T` being a union type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX7JDW) so the compiler can't safely assume that `gen(value)` is safe unless `value` is *both* an `ABC` *and* an `XYZ`.  There are ways to refactor to prevent that, possibly even with type safety, but the use case here is confusing to me.  Could you make the code here a [mre]? (e.g., do you need `s` and `t`? do you care about the return type of `gen()`? If not, maybe remove it from the example; if so, maybe add some code to the example that shows this)

Comment: I see you've removed `s` and `t`, but you're still just calling `gen(value)` without caring about the return type... it could be `void` for all anyone cares, since you're not doing anything but logging the value.  I'd suggest either changing it to `void` (instead of `ABC` and `XYZ` respectively) or doing something with the type (e.g., returning `gen(value)` from `test` so that the return type of `test` depends on the type).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL4Bam) meet your needs?  If so, I could write up an answer. If not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: `Extract<Params, {type: T}>` doesn't really do anything as is equivalent to `Params`.

Comment: @jcalz thx, the last approach works for me, but i still don't understand why compiler can't safely assume the type of 'gen(value)', why does it think that value should be 'ABC & XYZ'.

Comment: Did you see [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wX7JDW)?  Here I am calling `test()` where `T` is of type `"haha" | "yoyo"`, so it lets me pass a `gen()` that accepts an `XYZ` and a `value` that is an `ABC`.  No compiler error in that call to `test()`.  Among other things, that means the compiler is correct to not let you call `gen(value)`.  Is there something specific there that is confusing?

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the compiler is correct to complain that `gen(value)` is unsafe.  While the intended use case for `test()` is that `T` will *either* be of type `"haha"` *or* of type `"yoyo"`, nothing prevents someone from calling `test()` with `T` being the full [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"haha" | "yoyo"`.  Here's one way to get that to happen:

```
test(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'haha' : 'yoyo',
  { abc: 1 }, (n: XYZ) => console.log(n.xyz.toFixed()),
);
// T is "haha" | "yoyo"
```

The first argument to `test` is of type `"haha" | "yoyo"`.  Because of this, the compiler infers `T` to be `"haha" | "yoyo"`, which allows the second argument to be of type `ABC | XYZ` and the third argument to be of type `((x: ABC)=>void) | ((x: XYZ)=>void)`.  And so the compiler is perfectly happy to allow `value` to be of type `ABC` while `gen` is of type `(x: XYZ)=>void`.

But the above call to `test()` leads to a runtime error, because calling `gen(value)` inside of `test` is unsafe.  Since `gen` can be of type `((x: ABC)=>void) | ((x: XYZ)=>void)`, the only safe way to call it would be to give it an argument which will definitely not run into an error no matter which function type it actually is.  That has to be *both* an `ABC` *and* an `XYZ`, also known as [the intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `ABC & XYZ`.  (See [the TS3.3 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for the feature that interprets unions of functions as accepting intersections of arguments). So that explains the error message...

...but this isn't the use case you're trying to support; you don't want `T` to be the full union type.  Currently there is no way to tell the compiler that a type parameter can be only one member of a union; there's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) but it's not part of the language.

---

In order to support your intended use cases, where you are *either* calling `test()` with all `ABC` stuff *or* with all `XYZ` stuff, you will need to refactor.  And in order to have the compiler verify type safety, you will need to refactor in a certain way that has only been [supported since TS4.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#indexed-access-inference-improvements).

Here's the refactoring:

```
type ParamMap = { haha: ABC, yoyo: XYZ }
```

The `ParamMap` type is a helper type that keeps track of the relationship between the `type` names `"haha"`/`"yoyo"` and the `value` types `ABC`/`XYZ`.

```
type TestParams<T extends keyof ParamMap> = { [K in T]:
  [type: K, value: ParamMap[K], gen: (arg: ParamMap[K]) => void]
}[T];
```

Then `TestParams<T>` is a *distributive object type* as coined in the in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), the PR that enabled this refactoring.  A distributive object type is one in which you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over some set of keys and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with those same keys to get a union.  You can verify that `TestParams<"haha" | "yoyo">` evaluates to the following union type:

```
type TestParamsUnion = TestParams<"haha" | "yoyo">
// type TestParamsUnion = 
//   [type: "haha", value: ABC, gen: (arg: ABC) => void] | 
//   [type: "yoyo", value: XYZ, gen: (arg: XYZ) => void]
```

These [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) correspond to the parameter lists we want `test()` to support.  And indeed, `test()` now takes a rest argument of a `TestParams<T>` type:

```
function test<T extends keyof ParamMap>(...[type, value, gen]: TestParams<T>) {
  // (parameter) value: ParamMap[T]
  // (parameter) gen: (arg: ParamMap[T]) => void      
  console.log(type, value, gen(value)); // okay
}
```

The types of `gen` and `value` are now seen to be correlated in a way that the compiler can verify as safe.  `gen` takes an argument of type `ParamMap[T]` and `value` is a value of exactly that type.  So the call succeeds inside the implementation of `test()`.

And from the caller's side of `test()`, things are also good.  Supported calls are still accepted:

```
test('haha', { abc: 1 }, (n) => n); // okay
```

Whereas the call we accidentally allowed before is now prohibited, as desired:

```
test(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'haha' : 'yoyo',
  { abc: 1 }, (n: XYZ) => console.log(n.xyz.toFixed()),
); // error!
// Argument of type '["haha" | "yoyo", { abc: 1; }, (n: XYZ) => void]' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type 'TestParams<keyof ParamMap>'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJICWwALhAE4BmCyAggEIDCeJpSIARvAC4kARgDcXAL5EuFavUZIAGgE0AWp0LckADwCeWIQCZxmpFOKnQkWAoAKNAPa8MEMBq6lZtBoiQAJEAALEFsQGnAoDS1SSl0YCCEAcmDgxJNopAA3TABXBKRWNnTogHMIYCEACj5BAvYASiQAXgA+LIcyABNi0nMPcipvBWUHXQdQ8LBIglMtWPiksbG0-tJsjDyhFVUe7jKKpEq9AyU1Rtb2rt2+2aR55AmI5v8gkLCngB8kEbHHqZN+nQcsB4JQyA5gHdoJQADyrJAAFSQEG01GAnUifygAG1EvdEgBdAA08IAasjUeUMUgAKKo8KgmFYol4O5xfJIiQtXHrPKEkm3UgAcQpaOpdMoDNhzNZ9yEnO5iX2-PhLUq8Ji7PlAoya1y+VJOt1+yEQqNpEaMwy8AhUAcLgAdBgHCVKvcWbyICz9pVPfV6qIkAB6IPImiOGgAQn6Nzm0MqyVeiRZuB4-CEwjMLMqwHObVzANu1CglHVgqQAFkQJRAg7wuiHGBKo0YUgAAwOgCsSAA-EhE6kkItRg5k-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-TFqW8JVjWdYgA2TYtu2Xa9v296JEO-avmO5YTumH0SNms5nMFCNLva+2rjmG76Fuu77oex6nhdl60BG0a3JeTDpTkkBUH9xGgYk2JuQ+EUviOHlvVzYifXzqibdJzNkJEMOUJFKuhiAUBQGQJSgM4yDbkgg3gPNqNVWy8T9tZmEEURJETdxLSJA6X4WBIQA)

Comment: good, it's very clear.